# Wicket examples' SignInExample not working in IE8 on first attempt

Tags: authentication, internet-explorer-8, wicket

I'm basically duplicating the 'authentication' Wicket example from v1.4.x in SVN. It works fine in FireFox and Chrome but not in IE8.

When in IE8, after I click the submit button, it returns a 404 error. However, I can manually paste the "destination" URL in and it goes there fine (as an authenticated user). Another scenario is, I try to login, it gives me a 404, I hit refresh (looking at the HTML source I see the page version increment), re-login and it works fine.

To summarize:

1. When I try to log in the first time in IE8, it returns a 404 error. When I hit refresh and try to log in again, it works fine.
2. When I try to log in the first time in IE8, it returns a 404 error. When I manually paste the destination URL into the browser, it goes there fine, as if I'm logged in.

I've compared everything between IE8 and FireFox from the rendered source and the code is not doing anything special. What are the differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by mapping the `Index` page thus:

```
mountBookmarkablePage("/index", Index.class);
```